# Reverse string and capitalization

Tags: java, reverse

I need to write a class that takes a string of text from the user and **reverses the capitalization as well as the string**.
For example, if I input the string `Mary had a little lamb.`
The results would be `.BMAL ELTTIL A DAH YRAm`

I know you can use `StringBuilder` to reverse the string itself but I can't figure out a way to reverse the capitalization.

Thank you for your help and advice in advance!

Comment: Check each character, and use Character.isUpperCase / or Character.isLowerCase to test and reverse the capitalization.

Answer (score 3):

Simple method that swaps the case of a single character:

```
char swapCase(char c)
{
    return Character.isUppercase(c) ? 
           Character.toLowerCase(c) : 
           Character.toUpperCase(c)
}
```

Just use this while you're reversing the string, swapping the case along the way.

Answer (score 0):

To "reverse" the capitalization, you'll have to iterate through the `String`, character by character, and "flip" it. There isn't a built-in way to do it (because it's not anything anybody in real life would ever want to do :) ).

So, iterate through the String, getting each `char` one at a time, check it with `Character.isUpperCase()` and/or `Character.isLowerCase()` and then flip it using `Character.toUpperCase()` and/or `Character.toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bit information of a character to determine if its a capital letter. Or you could simply use the String class method isUpperCase or isLowerCase.

So you need to tests

```
if(string.charAt(i).isUpperCase) {
    string.charAt(i).toLowerCase
    simplyReverse(string.charAt(i))
}
else
    simplyReverse(string.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
String str = "Aasdf";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
    } else {
        sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
    }
}
sb.reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a char array:

```
public static String reverseAndCapitalize(final String input) {
    final char[] charsInput = input.toCharArray();
    final char[] charsOutput = new char[charsInput.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < charsInput.length; i++) {
        final char c = charsInput[i];
        final char output = Character.isUpperCase(c) ? Character.toLowerCase(c) : Character.toUpperCase(c);
        charsOutput[charsInput.length - i - 1] = c;
    }
    return new String(charsOutput);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this string to new array and convert the new array toUpperCase.

Then check for matching cases. If match found just convert it toLowerCase.

Pseudo Code:

```
reverse(String s) {
    sArray=s.toCharArray();
    copy sArray to tempArray;
    reverse both array;
    tempArray.toUpperCase();
    for(i=0;i<sArray.length; i++) {
      if(tempArray[i]== sArray[i]) {
            sArray[i].toLowerCase();
      }
    }
```

This code for writing code without using String builder.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution is with O(log(n)) time complexity and O(n) space complexity.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string reverse = SpecialReverse("PleaseReverseThisString");
            Console.WriteLine(reverse);
        }


private static string SpecialReverse(string v)
        {
            char[] str = v.ToCharArray();
            
            if(v.Length >1)
            {
                int length = (int)v.Length / 2;

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    var left = i;
                    var right = v.Length - 1 - i;

                    if (Char.IsUpper(str[left]) && !Char.IsUpper(str[right]))
                    {
                        str[left] = char.ToLower(str[left]);
                        str[right] = char.ToUpper(str[right]);
                    }
                    else if (!Char.IsUpper(str[left]) && Char.IsUpper(str[right]))
                    {
                        str[left] = char.ToUpper(str[left]);
                        str[right] = char.ToLower(str[right]);
                    }

                    Swap(str, left, right);
                }
            }
            
            return string.Join(string.Empty,str);
        }

        private static void Swap(char[] str, int i, int j)
        {
            var temp = str[i];
            str[i] = str[j];
            str[j] = temp;
        }
```